# Flagging the type of data ($, %, N/A) in Excel

Tags: excel

What's the best way to flag different types of data in a column?

I have a data set where I have a mixture of *dollar values, percentages, and N/As in Column B* and *I want to flag them by their type* as the calculation for each is different. Originally I thought going with a "Column B > 1" will help flag the dollar value ones, but that doesn't include all of it. Thank you!

[image: Sample Data Set]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the below formula.
=IF(ISTEXT(N3),"Red",IF(CELL("format",N3)="C2-","Green","Yellow"))

[image: Result Pic]

Comment: Slightly changed the formula so it catches whole numbers too:

**D2 = Reference Cell**

=IF(ISTEXT(D2),"Red",IF(OR(CELL("format",D2)="C0-",CELL("format",D2)="C2-"),"Green","Yellow"))

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/cell-function-51bd39a5-f338-4dbe-a33f-955d67c2b2cf

Comment: @AriMonger Agreed..:-)